# Access Inner Namespace from Outer without knowing inner name

Tags: c#, namespaces

I think I have painted myself into a corner here: Lets say I have a bunch of code that I use in multiple projects, so I put that in namespace `Company`.

Then all project-specific code goes in `Company.Project`. I can then call code in the library - the outer namespace - from the project namespace without having to specify the namespace - it's implicitly imported. Fine.

However, say I have some code that I use in all the projects, but which is implemented differently project by project. For the sake of example, lets say I have a diagnostic window and code that I might implement in WPF, or Winforms, or with a different look and feel for each project. As it's implemented project by project, it can't go in the `Company` namespace, but when it's in the project namespace, I can only call it from the `Company` namespace by specifying the inner namespace - which is going to be different for each project.

I guess I could use delegates to solve this but it seems messy - is there an easier way?

Comment: You have a project specific control that you want to reuse in other projects? Sorry it is not very clear to me, I couldn't understand exactly what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need some kind of IoC and use interfaces to solve this. Here's a simple one without any special libraries:

```
// In your shared project
namespace Company {
    public interface IDiagnosticWindow {
        void ShowMessage(string message);
    }

    public static class Utilities {

        private static IDiagnosticWindow _diagnosticWindow;

        public static void InitializeDiagnosticWindow(IDiagnosticWindow dw) {
            _diagnosticWindow = dw;
        }

        public static void ShowMessage(string message) {
            _diagnosticWindow.ShowMessage(message);
        }
    }
}

// In your WinForms project
namespace Company.WinForms {
    public class WinFormsDiagnosticWindow : IDiagnosticWindow {
        public void ShowMessage(string message) {
            MessageBox.Show(message);
        }
    }

    static void Main() {
        Utilities.InitializeDiagnosticWindow(new WinFormsDiagnosticWindow());
    }
}
```

Implement it similarly for each other application. In this example, it's important that you initialize this manually on the start of the app. But if you do this in `Main`, then this will be initialized, and `Utilities.ShowMessage` will be available for use in the core project or in your application project.

A library like Ninject can also help you out by hooking up this relationship a little better.

Comment: I was dimly groping towards this but couldn't quite get there- this code made it fall into place

Answer (score 4):

Maybe use an interface? Define the interface in your `Company` namespace. Then have each project implement the interface. Then use the interface in the `Company` namespace.

One drawback of this approach is that there still needs to be a class somewhere that creates the project-specific instance of the interface implementation. Like a factory of some sort which will need to have references to both the `Company` namespace and the project-specific class that implements it.